# Joomla k2 template override

Tags: joomla-k2, joomla-template, joomla-component, joomla3.3

I want to create template override for k2 item view.... I have a little problem (little, I think)

I want to put extra fields next to the item image.. (in item view)..

I trying it but not working properly.. 
If any one know how to do it help me. See the below image (to see exactly what I am asking)

http://postimg.org/image/aoeqqcay5/
Or
http://postimg.org/image/6o112077x/
Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the file item.php, of k2 template.

Let's suppose  are you using K2 Default template.
So, .../com_k2/templates/default/item.php

The code to show the extra fields is around line 250 (k2 V2.6) :

```
  <?php if($this->item->params->get('itemExtraFields') && count($this->item->extra_fields)): ?>
  <!-- Item extra fields -->
  <div class="itemExtraFields">
    <h3><?php echo JText::_('K2_ADDITIONAL_INFO'); ?></h3>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField): ?>
        <?php if($extraField->value != ''): ?>
        <li class="<?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even"; ?> type<?php echo ucfirst($extraField->type); ?> group<?php echo $extraField->group; ?>">
            <?php if($extraField->type == 'header'): ?>
            <h4 class="itemExtraFieldsHeader"><?php echo $extraField->name; ?></h4>
            <?php else: ?>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel"><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</span>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

You can put it before the intro text code (maybe line 227):

```
<?php if(!empty($this->item->fulltext)): ?>
```

Of course you will need to make some css adjustments.

I hope this help you.